# history.push is doing an extra redirect, and ignoring the search parameters, if the user is already on the redirect page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a simple `Navbar` with a `Form` within it:

```
const NavBar = () => {
   let history = useHistory()
   ...
   ...

   return (
     ...
     <Form inline onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
         <InputGroup style={{width: "90%"}}>
             <Form.Control id="navbar-search" placeholder="Pesquise" size="sm"/>
             <Form.Control as="select" size="sm">
                 <option>Ações</option>
                 <option>Declarações</option>
             </Form.Control>
             <InputGroup.Append  size="sm">
                 <Button size="sm" type="submit" variant="outline-secondary">
                     <SearchIcon fontSize="small" />
                 </Button>
             </InputGroup.Append>
         </InputGroup>
     </Form>
     ...
   )
```

`handleSubit` is suppose to redirect (using `history.push`) to a path that I'm going to use the input value as a search parameter. I'm using `react-router-dom`.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    let baseEndpoint = e.target[1].value === "Ações" ? "actions" : "quotes"
    history.push({
        pathname: `/${baseEndpoint}/query`,
        search: `?description=${e.target[0].value}`, 
    })
}
```

Everything looks good except if the user is in the page the `handleSubmit` is going to redirect, ie, at `/${baseEndpoint}/query`.

If the user is in this page, history goes to `/${baseEndpoint}/query?description=${e.target[0].value}` and re-renders automatically to `/${baseEndpoint}/query?`.

I've also tried using `history.replace`, but it didn't work.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    let baseEndpoint = e.target[1].value === "Ações" ? "actions" : "quotes"
    let url = `/${baseEndpoint}/query`
    if(history.location.pathname === url) {
        history.replace({
            pathname: url,
            search: `?description=${e.target[0].value}`, 
        })
        return
    }
    history.push({
        pathname: url,
        search: `?description=${e.target[0].value}`, 
    })
}
```

What is causing this behaviour? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

(EDIT) My `Switch` and `Route`s:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";


class Wrapper extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Container className="main">
          <MetaData />
          <Navbar />
          <this.props.component {...this.props} />
          <br />
          <br />
          <Footer />
        </Container>
      </>
    )
  }
}


export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/"
          render={props => (
            <Wrapper {...props} component={Home} />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          exact path="/actions"
          key="action-home"
          render={props => (
            <Wrapper
              {...props}
              image={bozoAction}
              baseEndpoint="actions"
              component={EntityHome}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="/actions/query"
          key="action-query"
          render={props => (
            <Wrapper
              {...props}
              image={bozoAction}
              baseEndpoint="actions"
              component={EntityQuery}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="/actions/:id(\d+)"
          key="action-entity"
          render={props => (
            <Wrapper
              {...props}
              image={bozoAction}
              baseEndpoint="actions"
              component={Entity}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          exact path="/quotes"
          key="quote-home"
          render={props => (
            <Wrapper
              {...props}
              image={bozoQuote}
              baseEndpoint="quotes"
              component={EntityHome}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="/quotes/query"
          key="quote-query"
          render={props => (
            <Wrapper
              {...props}
              image={bozoQuote}
              baseEndpoint="quotes"
              component={EntityQuery}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="/quotes/:id(\d+)"
          key="quote-entity"
          render={props => (
            <Wrapper
              {...props}
              image={bozoQuote}
              baseEndpoint="quotes"
              component={Entity}
            />
          )}
        />
        ...
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/0y8cm

Form some reason the sandbox is not redirecting and ignoring the search parameters, but we can evaluate the error doing the following: use the navbar to search one of the entities. Check the form (clicking in "Mais filtros") and see the provided query param at the input. Do another search in the navbar to the same entity. Check the form and see no initial values.

Comment: are you by any chance using a <Redirect> component somewhere? Can you post the code with your switch and routes?

Comment: @dglozano I'm not using `<Redirect />` anywhere, altough I tried to use it following the same approach. I just uptade the question with the switch and routes.

Comment: Cant manage to reproduce with the code posted here. Could you maybe upload code for `EntityQuery`?

Comment: @dglozano I just provide a sandbox link with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's causing the behavior is the form submission event, it refreshes the page resulting in the loss of the query params, the solution to this is `e.preventDefault()` when you submit the form :

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {

  e.preventDefault(); // prevent the page refresh

  let baseEndpoint = e.target[1].value === "Ações" ? "actions" : "quotes";
  history.push({
    pathname: `/${baseEndpoint}/query`,
    search: `?description=${e.target[0].value}`
  });
};
```

You can add `history.go()` if you absolutely have to refresh the page, but i wouldn't recommend that, the goal is to let the child components know that the `search` has changed,

The way your `EntityQuery` and `QueryForm` is set up makes it impossible for the child components to know if there is a change, so you need to fix that,

You shouldn't set the initial state value from the props in the constructor as it's [anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e) , instead, have the initial values `empty` and use life cycle methods to update them ( `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` )

**EntityQuery**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: true,
      hasMore: false,
      searchParams: {
        page: 1,
        tags: "",
        description: ""
      },
      entities: []
    }
  }

  updateStateValues = () => {
    const _initialTag = this.props.location.search.includes("tags")
      ? this.props.location.search.split("?tags=")[1]
      : "";
    const _initialText = this.props.location.search.includes("description")
      ? this.props.location.search.split("?description=")[1]
      : "";

    this.setState({
      searchParams: {
        page: 1,
        tags: _initialTag,
        description: _initialText
      }
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateStateValues()
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    // add checks for other potential props that you need to update if they change
    if (prevProps.location.search.split("?description=")[1] !== this.props.location.search.split("?description=")[1])
      this.updateStateValues()
  }
```

And pass the values from the `state` to the child :

```
<QueryForm
    baseEndpoint={this.props.baseEndpoint}
    tagsInitialValues={this.state.searchParams.tags}
    textInitialValue={this.state.searchParams.description}
    setSearchParams={this.setSearchParams}
 />
```

[Updated CodePen](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-joliot-w2n3p)

**EDIT:**

Fllowing up the OP's comment and the updated SandBox, there's another issue regarding `Formik` where the `initialValues` do not update when the `props` change, see : https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/811

The suggested solution of adding `enableReinitialize` didn't work, so, to force the component to update, you can use a `key` that changes when the url changes, in this case, use `this.props.textInitialValue` :

**QueryForm :**

```
<Formik
  key={this.props.textInitialValue}
  ...
```

Comment: It turns out that I omit some code that won't let your solution work. I edited the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/0y8cm

Comment: I' m quite sure it is in the `_fetchTagsWhitelist` function. Thanks in advance for the anti-pattern tip (you'll find it this anti-pattern withing another component - apologise a backend guy learning frontend, please :))

Comment: @MuriloSitonio i updated the answer, it seems to be an issue with `Formik`

Comment: Thanks again! Unfortunately I ran into another issue. I'm not going to edit this question again so I made another one about it (if you like to take a look I'd be extremely grateful): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66788611/why-i-cant-set-the-state-from-inside-componentdidupdate-even-with-a-condition

Comment: Also, if I set the state from the props from `componentDidMount` it just doesn't work.

Comment: @MuriloSitonio i see that the other issue is resolved, still having trouble with `componentDidMount` ? in which component ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `e.prevenDefault()` at the start of the `handleSubmit` function.

Maybe `<form>` submission is causing a page reload and hence, removing the search parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This won't work because I need the page to reload to make the new query. I just edited the question with a sandbox link, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try to prevent the default behavior of the form on submission by changing your `handleSubmit()` handler to:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()
    let baseEndpoint = e.target[1].value === "Ações" ? "actions" : "quotes"
    history.push({
        pathname: `/${baseEndpoint}/query`,
        search: `?description=${e.target[0].value}`, 
    })
}
```

Let me if it works *

Comment: Thanks for the response! This won't work because I need the page to reload to make the new query. I just edited the question with a sandbox link, thanks again!