# Why I can't set the state from inside componentDidUpdate even with a condition?

Tags: reactjs

I'm comparing props from within `componentDidUpdate` and trying to update the state and, after that, fetch some data (which depends of some state params).

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.location.search.split("?description=")[1] !==
        this.props.location.search.split("?description=")[1]) {
        this.setState({
            searchParams: this.getInitialSearchParams(),
            isLoaded: false,
            entities: []
        })
        this.fetchMore()
    }
    
}
```

But, as the question suggests, when I'm going to fetch the data, the function is using a previous state.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/0y8cm

To evaluate the error do the following: use the navbar to search one of the entities. Check the console to see the state. Do another search in the navbar to the same entity. Check the console again and see the unchanged state.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `setState` is asynchronous and the value is not set immediately after the call. You should use its callback to follow up.

```
setState(updater, [callback]);
```

This is useful for when you want to use the state values right after updating them. So instead you would have:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.location.search.split("?description=")[1] !==
        this.props.location.search.split("?description=")[1]) {
        this.setState({
            searchParams: this.getInitialSearchParams(),
            isLoaded: false,
            entities: []
        }, this.fetchMore); //or () => this.fetchMore() if you want to send params
    }
    
}
```

You can read more about `setState` here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

It's very useful to read about the setState and React's lifecycle as well.

Hope this was helpful.